# Java combining sockets with web services

Tags: web-services, sockets

I have an older statusing application that uses DataGramSockets to send/rec status messages from a number of programs. I want to convert this reporting app to use web services so it can also be queried from web pages.

Is it possible to have both the socket listening on its usual port while another service, second thread, listen to an http port for web connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will be using web sockets at this point. I see there really is no perfect answer to this question and its a little open ended. Ill get it closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Java socket.io Library (for example) to use websocket/websocket secure over http/https.